# How do you obtain the sum a specific property of an object in an array of objects in Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects.  I'd like to be able to create a function that will sum and return each of the isSaved fields that are true.

```
var arrInductedInfo = [];
var InductedInfo = function () { };
InductedInfo.prototype = {
    SerialNumber: null,
    isSaved: false,

    TestData: function (msg) {
        this.testfield = msg;
        alert(this.testfield);
    }
};
```

I am currently using this method, but, as you can see, i'm using the array name.  I mean, it works... but its not really reusable as such in that I'm calling a specific instance of an array:

```
InductedInfo.prototype.TotalSaved = function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var isSaved in arrInductedInfo) {
        if (isSaved) total += 1;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a more generic fashion?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: pass the array to the function?

Comment: Or give each instance of `InductedInfo` it's own array.

Comment: Both work, but i'd already thought of and rejected the first.  I'll take Mike's as an answer if you post it.  Thanks both of you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a function in the `Array.prototype`. You can't do that in the `InductedInfo.prototype`.

```
Array.prototype.totalInductedInfoSaved = function() {
    var tot = 0;
    for (var i=0, el; el = this[i]; i++) {
        if (el instanceof InductedInfo && el.isSaved) tot ++;
    }
    return tot;
}

var arr = [new InductedInfo(), new InductedInfo()];
arr[0].isSaved = true;
arr.totalInductedInfoSaved();

> 1

arr[1].isSaved = true;
arr.totalInductedInfoSaved();

> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that each `InductedInfo` has it's own array to operate on, you could add one as a property in the constructor:

```
var InductedInfo = function() {
    this.arr = [];
};
```

Then your `TotalSaved` function would look like this:

```
InductedInfo.prototype.TotalSaved = function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var isSaved in this.arr) {
        if (isSaved) total += 1;
    }
    return total;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for a library that provides some functional style methods.

You can use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) with reduce to do just this.

```
var sum = _.reduce(arrInductedInfo, function(memo, item){ return memo + (item.isSaved ? 1 : 0); }, 0);
```

Comment: He could also just use [the native reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if he's not supporting legacy browsers.

Comment: while potentially helpful this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @sgroves: The OP asked for a solution possibly using jQuery.  If we extend that to mean "using an external library", then this suggestion in perfectly fit.